# How to configure ibm watson (speech to text API) in unity for developing AR application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-to-text, android-augmented-reality

I've been trying to make an AR application using IBM Watson (speech to text API). Unfortunately can't configure the API in unity. After importing the SDK can't find any options for configuration. Can anyone please tell me, how can I do that?

Here are my IDE details:
unity 5.6.5f1 Personal
vuforia unity SDK

[image: screenshot of my unity]

Answer (score 1):

Credential configuration menu has been deprecated since v1.0.0 of the SDK. You will need to configure the credentials manually.

```
void Start()
{
    Credentials credentials = new Credentials(<username>, <password>, <url>);
    SpeechToText _speechToText = new SpeechToText(credentials);
}
```

Please see [ExampleStreaming.unity](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/tree/develop/Examples/ServiceExamples) and [ExampleStreaming.cs](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/develop/Examples/ServiceExamples/Scripts/ExampleStreaming.cs).

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Microsoft Speech to Text as an alternative. But it was helpful though.